# Instance variables and threading

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have a class like the below and am wondering, will this be thread-safe or can the main thread and the `Loader` thread possibly have their own copys of the `mCache` and therefore the get(..) method fail to retreive anything from the cache as it was added in the loader thread? Do i need to mark this `volatile`?

Thanks!!

```
public class StackExample
{
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

    private addToCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        mCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String key)
    {
        if(mCache.contains(key))
        {
            return mCache.get(key);
        }
        else
        {
            //add to loading queue
        }
    }

    private class Loader extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            ...//check loading queue and load some images here
            mCache.put(keyString, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(loadedBitmap));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll only have a unique *mCache* visible to all threads but your code still isn't properly synchronized.  You *may* enter twice (or more than that) the *//add to loading queue* part of your code for a same *key* although from your example it's not entirely clear where *getBitmap* is called from (it's apparently private!?).

Comment: btw +1 to your question and shame on the people who upvoted Jon Skeet's one line answer without also upvoting your very fine question.

Comment: thanks! Yes just a quick example there, i do know what you mean in regards to the get method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is final, so it will be visible to all threads before the constructor (empty in this case) returns.

Comment: does it not matter that it is mutable? Is a final field never susceptible to threads holding their own copys?

Comment: @Dori: What do you think would be copied? `ConcurrentHashMap` is mutable but *designed* to be used by multiple threads without locking.

Comment: sorry, i was under the probably incorrect impression that all variables were able to be held as local copyies by each thread that uses them, with resulted in a thread possibly not being able to view the changes another thread has made to that variable. In some circunstances the volatile keyword can prevent this but does not stop interleaved operations. Also i thought synchronised stopped interleaved operations but I am unsure what effect it has on the local copy/caching of variables - when the sycnronised block starts/exits does the variable get refreshed / pushed to main memory?

Comment: @Dori: But the value of the variable is *only* the reference - not the object. And that variable is final, so the value can't be changed. See the memory model part of the Java Language Specification for more details.

Comment: ok thanks jon, a doc i obviously need to read! I take it that if I used a normal hashMap i could run into problems here?

Comment: @Dori: Yes, because then you'd be using the same object from multiple threads without any locking - and HashMap isn't safe for that.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` means that each thread will not keep a cache of the value of the field. If you were able to write to the mCache field then you would declare it volatile if you wanted to be sure that another thread got the new value when reading the field immediately after it was set by another thread.

Comment: from the above i thought this would not fit in the case as the field is just a reference and final

Comment: exactly. No reason to declare it volatile when it cannot change